# Combining Base Attack Bonuses

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e

When multiclassing or starting as a monster in pathfinder and AD&D3.5 is the BAB combined between all the classes to follow the standard progression or is it totalled up separately?

I.e.

Does a Rogue 4 (BAB 3) Fighter 4 (BAB 4) have a BAB of 7 or +7/+2 ?

And would an Monster (of BAB 4) Fighter 3 (BAB 4) have a BAB of 8 or +8/+3 ?

Comment: D&D 3.5e PHB; Pg 59 "Multiclass Characters", "Class Level and Features"; Paragraph 3, "Base Attack Bonus", Line 9: "A [total] base attack bonus of +6 allows a second attack with a bonus of +1 . . . even though neither the +4 from the rogue levels nor the +2 from the wizard levels normally allows an extra attack."

-1 for lack of research

Comment: (And assuming you don't have the book, both d20SRD and d20PFSRD have the info in the first search result for "Multiclass")

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**The two expressions are equal.**

Every time the attack bonus reaches +6, you gain another attack at your full BAB -5 (that is: +1); but you must use the full attack action. You gain an additional attack at +11 (the additional attack is at your full BAB -10) and +16 (full BAB -15), independently by how you sum up our BAB ([source](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Base-Attack-Bonus-BAB-)).

Stating that a creature has a BAB +13, inherently implies that it has 3 attacks with the full attack action:

- the 1<sup>st</sup> at full attack bonus (+13),
- the 2<sup>nd</sup> at full attack bonus -5 (+8), and
- the 3<sup>rd</sup> at full attack bonus -10 (+3)

So, BAB +13 = BAB +13/+8/+3.

Comment: Great, thanks; I was about 95% sure that was the case but just couldn't find the source for it.

Comment: Note, however, that monsters using natural weapons don't gain the additional attacks (aka "Iterative Attacks"). You only gain iterative attacks with manufactured weapons.